# How to do in Ruby on Jets if a new column is added to database table

Tags: ruby, rubyonjets

We need to alter table by adding a new column, in Ruby on Jets, what should be done? on database side, we can add column manually. how about Ruby on Jets files?

Thanks
George

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should mention your **database Name** as

- If you are using 
  **Dynamodb**

  You must go through https://rubyonjets.com/docs/database/dynamodb/

  or here you will find all the steps to follow for dynomoDb https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-ruby-on-aws-lambda-with-the-jets-framework
- If You are using **MongoDB**

  You must go through

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwUu1_jMNUQ
  https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/getting-started-rails/#create-new-application
  https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html
  https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#query_plus
- If you are using **MySQL** you just need to use normal migrations.

  Hope this would help you to catch the nearby solutions.
  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should use database migrations: https://rubyonjets.com/docs/database/activerecord/